# Docker Named Volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

What's the right way to mix named volumes with and without local host path in docker compose v3?
This way I'm getting YML error:

```
volumes:
  /mnt/volume-part1:/volume
  conf:
  vhost:
  html:
  certs:
```

Then I'd like to refer to *volume* inside containers...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For named volumes, you need to declare the volume name under the dedicated volumes section in the compose file. For a mount, you don't declare it in that section:
Consider the following compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: db
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/db
      - /mnt/volume-part1:/volume

volumes:
  data-volume:
```

As you can see the named volume `data-volume` needes to be declared in the volumes section before being assiged to the container. 
Whereas the directory mount is directly mounted onto the container.

**UPDATE**

If you don't want  to replicate the machine path on all the container, you can use a clever trick to specify where exactly the named volume will be created as such:

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: db
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/db
      - volume-part1:/volume

volumes:
  data-volume:
  volume-part1:
   driver_opts:
     type: none
     device: /mnt/volume-part1
     o: bind
```

As you can see above, we have created a named volume `volume-part1` and specified where this volume will be backuped on the host machine.

Comment: So I've to attach *mnt* to a specific container or replicate it for every container that needs it. Is that right? I ask it, because I'd like to avoid hardcoding a host machine path that way...

Comment: Many thanks, just a curiosity: is it normal that data-volume has no *:* in the last volumes section?

Comment: The `:` was missing.